# Add prefix / suffix to dataframe name or pass 'parameter' into dataframe name in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I pass parameter in python to create new dataframe each time for example :

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(10):
    df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=list('abc'))
    print i , df
```

This will give me a different dataframe df each time, but I want my df output to be dataframe named :

```
df1 , df2, df3 , df4 ..
```

===============================================

```
import numpy as np
name = ['one','two','three']
for i in range(3):
    name_df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=list('abc'))
    print i , name_df
```

This second example I would like my dataframe names to be

```
one, two, three
```

================================================

here below as a function

```
def data(t):
    df_%s , %t = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=list('abc'))
    print df_%s , %t
data('a')
data('b')
```

here in the function I would like to get output dataframe named :

```
df_a , df_b
```

Comment: just create dictionary with DataFrames `{'one': <...>, 'two': <...>}` or list with DataFrames

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you can name exactly as you have mentioned but you can instead create dictionary of dataframe like this:

```
>>> df={}
>>> for i in range(5):
    df[str(i)] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=list('abc'))
```

And access them as `df['0'],df['1'], etc.`

If you must need to name it like that you can use this,

```
for i in range(5):
    vars()['df_' +str(i)] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=list('abc'))
```

And if you need to set the name withing a function it will only be available withing the function as it will a local variable. In which case you can use the dict one.