# Add string to dataframe name as function output

Tags: python, function, pandas

I'd like to add a string to the end of my function result, with the output like this:

```
def fcn(df) :
    return df_v2
```

How can I add that '_v2' to the original df's name? (For example df_foo becomes df_foo_v2.)

If there's a way to do it where the suffix is defined as part of the function then that would be even better! Like:

```
def fcn(df, x) :
    return df_x
```

Where x is input by the user to define what the suffix of the result it.

I've looked at this question but wondering if there's a way to do it without the dictionary of df's.
[Add prefix / suffix to dataframe name or pass 'parameter' into dataframe name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237454/add-prefix-suffix-to-dataframe-name-or-pass-parameter-into-dataframe-name-in)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by variable name change? How is this varisble used later? Your variable at return statement is a local one, how does renaming it help in  your bigger program?

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak I'd like to return a modified dataframe (under a modified name) while also retaining the original dataframe for use later on.

Comment: I've had a lightbulb moment that I should have realised ages ago. I can just save the return df as a new df with a different name...

Oops.

And thanks.

Comment: that sounds like a better way to go, glad you changed your variable path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about saving a DataFrame as a dictionary where the key would be the name of a DF:

```
dct = {}

dct['df_v2'] = df
```

to rename `df_foo` to `df_foo_v2`

```
dct['df_foo_v2'] = dct.pop('df_foo', None)
```

Comment: I've had a lightbulb moment that I should have realised ages ago. I can just save the return df as a new df with a different name...

Oops.

And thanks.