# How to add a suffix to dataframe in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, function

I want to create a preprocessing function that would add a suffix to the dataframe name.

This will allow me to easily identify my dataframes without or with feature scaling and the technique used if applicable.

For example:

```
mas = MaxAbsScaler()


def preproce_MaxAbsScaler(df):
    [df+str("_mas")]=pd.DataFrame(mas.fit_transform(df),
                           index=df.index,
                           columns=df.columns)
    return [df+str("_mas")]
```

Comment: I think this topic can help you:
[Create variable name from two string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373618/create-variable-name-from-two-string-in-python)

Comment: Thank you is a good topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add a suffix to the dataframe name.
>
> This will allow me to easily identify

Variables names inside function are contained therein, consider that

```
def func(x):
    y = x + 1
    return y
func(42)
print(y)
```

lead to

```
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

You might elect to just set attribute of `pandas.DataFrame` which is not name of method or column thereof, for example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1],'Y':[2],'Z':[3]})
df.comment = "example dataframe"
```

and then access in normal way of using instance attributes

```
print(df.comment)  # example dataframe
```

Comment: Yes you are right, that makes sense, might as well create a copy of the df with the suffix added before using the function.

The idea of ​​the comment is very judicious, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `add_suffix` to solve this issue:

```
#Example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [3, 4, 5, 6]})
df.add_suffix('_MyDataFrame')
```

Comment: This will add a suffix to the column names not to the dataframe name.

Comment: Oh my bad. I think you will find your solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237454/add-prefix-suffix-to-dataframe-name-or-pass-parameter-into-dataframe-name-in